# Transpose columns to rows keeping first 3 columns the same

Tags: vba, excel

I have data in the following format:
[image: Data]

Is there a way to transpose the columns to rows keeping the ticket number (A), Date (B) , and Invoice (C) on each row and creating new rows based on the number that splits up each set of data (columns D-AI)? There can be up to 10 sets of data but there are not always 10 under each invoice.

This is the result I am looking to achieve:
[image: Result]

The data is initially imported in from 2 columns and transposed to rows using the following macro (based on the ticket # in column A):

```
Dim r       As Long
Dim c       As Long
r = 1
c = 2
For Each Cell In Rng
    ShNew.Cells(r, c).Value = Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
    With Rng
        If Cell.Value <> Cell.Offset(1, 0).Value Then
            ShNew.Cells(r, 1).Value = Cell.Value
            r = r + 1
            c = 2
        Else
            c = c + 1
        End If
    End With
Next Cell
```

It is then formatted to extract the result that is shown in the first picture above.

Is there any way to get the result I am looking for? Would it be easier to do this without initially formatting the 2 rows into columns?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Could you share sample workbook? :)

Comment: I think you are talking about pivoting rather than transposing

Comment: Here is a [Sample Workbook](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PTrLS-YP4UwONh7RrCOkE27Pbv-XZytw/view?usp=drivesdk). The first tab is how the data is initially imported, the second tab is what I was able to do with the formatting, and the last tab is my desired result. Thank you!

Comment: I'd keep it in original format. That would be way easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a tricky one for me.

Here is what I came up with. I had to make some assumptions about your data. I think this method is *really* close to being what you are after.

**Output Data - what the code outputs now**

```
1111111111  2017-12-16 3:56 123456789   1   QCOM    2017-12-15  A   COMPLETE
2222222222  2017-12-16 3:56 987654321   1   MCD     2017-12-15  A   COMPLETE
3333333333  2017-12-16 3:56 123123123   1   QCOM    2017-12-15      
3333333333  2017-12-16 3:56 123123123   2   T       2017-12-15  A   COMPLETE
4444444444  2017-12-16 3:56 456456456   1   VZ      2017-12-15      
4444444444  2017-12-16 3:56 456456456   2   F       2017-12-15      
4444444444  2017-12-16 3:56 456456456   3   BO      2017-12-15  A   COMPLETE
5555555555  2017-12-16 3:56 789789789   1   T       2017-12-15      
5555555555  2017-12-16 3:56 789789789   2   CVX     2017-12-15      
5555555555  2017-12-16 3:56 789789789   3   COTY    2017-12-15      
5555555555  2017-12-16 3:56 789789789   4   FTS     2017-12-15      
5555555555  2017-12-16 3:56 789789789   5   IBM     2017-12-15      
5555555555  2017-12-16 3:56 789789789   6   MRK     2017-12-15      
5555555555  2017-12-16 3:56 789789789   7   PX      2017-12-15      
5555555555  2017-12-16 3:56 789789789   8   PG      2017-12-15      
5555555555  2017-12-16 3:56 789789789   9   TGT     2017-12-15      
5555555555  2017-12-16 3:56 789789789   10  F       2017-12-15  COMPLETE
```

As you can notice the last entry doesn't quite match your desired data set. Is this an expected entry? This entry seems different than the others given the rule set in the code below. That being said, it shouldn't be too much more effort to add one special case, so I thought I'd share the method I came up with.

You will need to create a sheet called **Output** for this to work as is. I'm outputting the results as shown in **Output Data** section.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Format_Data()
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler:

    Dim inputSheet          As Worksheet
    Dim outputSheet         As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow             As Long
    Dim lastColumn          As Integer
    Dim rowCounter          As Long
    Dim outputArray()       As Variant
    Dim newItemCounter      As Long
    Dim colCounter          As Integer
    Const stepSize As Byte = 3

    Set inputSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Formatted")
    Set outputSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Output")

    lastRow = inputSheet.Cells(inputSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    If lastRow = 0 Then Err.Raise "1234", , "No Data in inputSheet!"

    'Make lots of room to add records
    ReDim outputArray(0 To 7, 0 To 10000)

    For rowCounter = 1 To lastRow

        With inputSheet

            'get the last column
            lastColumn = GetLastColumn(inputSheet, rowCounter)

            'In this condition there is only one entry
            If lastColumn = 8 Then
                outputArray(0, newItemCounter) = .Range("A" & rowCounter).Value
                outputArray(1, newItemCounter) = .Range("B" & rowCounter).Value
                outputArray(2, newItemCounter) = .Range("C" & rowCounter).Value
                outputArray(3, newItemCounter) = .Range("D" & rowCounter).Value
                outputArray(4, newItemCounter) = .Range("E" & rowCounter).Value
                outputArray(5, newItemCounter) = .Range("F" & rowCounter).Value
                outputArray(6, newItemCounter) = .Range("G" & rowCounter).Value
                outputArray(7, newItemCounter) = .Range("H" & rowCounter).Value
                newItemCounter = newItemCounter + 1

            ElseIf lastColumn > 8 Then

                For colCounter = 4 To lastColumn Step stepSize
                    'Make sure the value isn't null and the cell is numeric. This
                    'is the autonumber in columns
                    If Not .Cells(rowCounter, colCounter).Value = vbNullString _
                    And IsNumeric(.Cells(rowCounter, colCounter).Value) Then

                        outputArray(0, newItemCounter) = .Range("A" & rowCounter).Value
                        outputArray(1, newItemCounter) = .Range("B" & rowCounter).Value
                        outputArray(2, newItemCounter) = .Range("C" & rowCounter).Value
                        outputArray(3, newItemCounter) = .Cells(rowCounter, colCounter).Value
                        outputArray(4, newItemCounter) = .Cells(rowCounter, colCounter + 1).Value
                        outputArray(5, newItemCounter) = .Cells(rowCounter, colCounter + 2).Value

                        'Add additional fields if needed...this is seemingly indicated
                        'by a non numeric column
                        If Not IsNumeric(.Cells(rowCounter, colCounter + stepSize).Value) Then
                            outputArray(6, newItemCounter) = .Cells(rowCounter, colCounter + 3).Value
                            outputArray(7, newItemCounter) = .Cells(rowCounter, colCounter + 4).Value
                        End If

                        'keep track of where we are in the array
                        newItemCounter = newItemCounter + 1
                    End If
                Next

            Else
                'What happens when data isn't correct format?
                'add this exception here!
            End If

        End With

    Next

    'Resize the array and output
    ReDim Preserve outputArray(0 To 7, 0 To newItemCounter)
    outputSheet.Range("A1:H" & newItemCounter).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(outputArray)

CleanExit:
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    Select Case Err.Number
        Case 1234
            Debug.Print Err.Description
    End Select

    Resume CleanExit
End Sub

'Helper function to get the last Contiguous column with data
'from left to right
Private Function GetLastColumn(currentSheet As Worksheet, rowCounter As Long)
    Dim colNumber As Integer

    For colNumber = 1 To 5000
        If currentSheet.Cells(rowCounter, colNumber).Value = vbNullString Then Exit For
    Next

    GetLastColumn = colNumber - 1
End Function
```

Comment: Wow, that is exactly what I was trying to do. My mistake on the last entry, my original formatting macro did not pull over the entire thing. I really appreciate your time, as you saw I could only get the tickets on separate lines but not the actual requests on separate lines. This will help a lot!

For the exception part I will just have the ticket move to a needs review tab if the data is not in the correct format.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad this helped :)

Comment: The macro worked initially but now it is not pulling over any data. I ran the code line by line and when it gets to 
outputSheet.Range("A1:H" & newItemCounter).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(outputArray) it jumps to the ErrorHandler. Do you know why this would happen? It's not actually giving me any error message, it's just not pulling the data over to the Output tab. The odd thing is it worked the first time I tried it this morning.

Comment: It's going to the error handler because there is an error. Print out the error, e.g. Debug.Print Err.Number, Err.Description, or turn off the error handler to let it fail

Comment: Run-time error '13': Type Mismatch. I think I figured out the problem. One of the comment cells in the last column is 288 characters. When I change the cell contents it works.

Comment: If the contents go above 255 characters you will need to manually transpose the data. Here's some code that'll do that: https://bettersolutions.com/vba/arrays/transposing.htm. E.g. this would replace the `Worksheetfunction.Transpose` operation