# turn rows into columns and coping and keeping the same index infrond of all previous together columns

Tags: pivot, rows

the inverse of 
[Transpose columns to rows keeping first 3 columns the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47874715/transpose-columns-to-rows-keeping-first-3-columns-the-same)

turn:

```
id  col1 col2 col3
1    A    B   
2    X    Y   Z
```

into:

```
id
1  A
1  B
2  X
2  Y
2  Z
```

I'm trying unpivot() but from the solution, I cited I need to use .unstack() ?